# A question on soundness and consistency of propositional logic

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am trying to prove the equivalence of two ways soundness of propositional logic is presented.

Soundness version 1 : If  $\Gamma \vdash A$ then $\Gamma \models A$.

Soundness version 2 : If $\Gamma$ has a model (Satisfiable) then $\Gamma$ is consistent

As part of the proof from version 2 to version 1, I need to prove that if $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot\phi\}$ has no model, then $\Gamma \models \phi$.

How do I prove this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of "consistent"? Which proof system does $\vdash$ stand for?

Comment: if $Γ ∪ \{ ¬ϕ \}$ has no model, this means that in every model of $Γ$ , $¬ϕ$ is false, i.e. $ϕ$ is true, i.e. $Γ \vDash ϕ$.

Comment: By consistency, I mean there is no formula A such that  Γ⊢A and  Γ⊢¬A

Comment: The proof system that I'm working in is Hilbert style.

Answer (score 1):

If $$\Gamma\not \models A$$ that means that there is a model of $\Gamma\cup\{\neg A\}$ and so by $2$, $\Gamma\cup\{\neg A\}$ is consistent. Therefore $$\Gamma\not \vdash A$$ ]eg

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense now